# PostgresSQL bool_or equivalent in Spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to convert a PostgreSQL query to spark

```sql
 select 
    bool_or(case when col_1 is null then false else true end),
    bool_or(col_2)
 from fct_table
```

Below is the dataframe I am trying to work with that has col_1 and col_2:

```
val df = spark.table("fct_table")
df.agg(
bool_or(when(col("col_1") isNull,false).otherwise(true))
bool_or("col_2")
)
```

I'm doing this in scala and bool_or is not an aggregate function.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sum`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def bool_or(expr: Column) = sum(expr.cast("integer")) > 0
```

With `count`

```
def bool_or(expr: Column) = count(when(expr, lit(1))) > 0
```

Comment: getting error while using any one of the above

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported